# Using iterrows() to modify column in dataframe - Type Error

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to using iterrows(). I want to update the strings in the column Time depending on the length of the string and modify accordingly. I am getting a Type Error.

```
def time_edits(x):
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        if df.loc[idx, len('time')] == 2:
            df.loc[idx, 'time'] = '0' + df.loc[idx, 'time'] + '0'
        elif df.loc[idx, len('time')] == 3:
            df.loc[idx, 'time'] = '0' + df.loc[idx, 'time']
        else:
            df.loc[idx, 'time']
        return

df["time"].apply(time_edits)
```

The expected output is to modify the column in place depending on the length of the string.

```
TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [4] of <class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work.

iterrows() iterates on all the rows of the dataframe. In the `apply` you apply a function to each register. So what you're saying there is: to each register in column 'time', iterate on all its rows, etc.

As you can see, it makes no much sense.

I think the following should work:

```py
def time_edits(x):
    if len(x) == 2:
        return [desired output in this case]
    elif len(x) == 3:
        return [desired output in this case]
    else:
        return [desired output in this case]
```

To save the result on the original column:

```py
df["time"] = df["time"].apply(time_edits)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! It really helps. I finally got it to work

Comment: You're welcome! If it solved your question, please mark it as the accepted answer with the tick below the votes.

Answer (score 0):

The `df.loc` takes *the row id and the column name*, not length of columns. So you should rewrite the code as following: 
Instead of `if df.loc[idx, len('time')] == 2`, 
you should use `if len(df.loc[idx, 'time']) == 2`

And if using `iterrows()` then need not to use `apply`.